# Displaying filtered markers as polylines on maps API

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get my map to draw polylines between different markers. The idea is that there are six groups of markers; Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo, Foxtrot.

The coordinates are stored in a database, which is being read by a php document, which puts the markers in a XML file.

My XML output data looks like this:

```
    <markers>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Echo" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="51.980434" lng="5.653239"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Delta" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="51.872005" lng="5.429794"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Charlie" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="51.850761" lng="5.959484"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Charlie" dag="zaterdag" tijd="19:20" lat="51.852547" lng="5.962409"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Bravo" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="51.935303" lng="6.285142"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Alpha" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="52.091156" lng="5.983163"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Foxtrot" dag="zaterdag" tijd="10:30" lat="52.142597" lng="5.700851"/>
<marker type="Hunt" deelgebied="Echo" dag="zaterdag" tijd="19:32" lat="51.978531" lng="5.770242"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Foxtrot" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="52.144386" lng="5.703785"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Echo" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="51.982224" lng="5.656161"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Delta" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="51.873802" lng="5.432700"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Charlie" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="51.853436" lng="0.000000"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Bravo" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="51.937077" lng="6.288086"/>
<marker type="Hint" deelgebied="Alpha" dag="zondag" tijd="19:00" lat="52.094730" lng="5.987297"/>
</markers>
```

As you can see, All markers have got a type, which is either hint or hunt. And they've got a value 'deelgebied'.

This is the code responsible for displaying the map and the markers. Apart from the markers, another KML file is loaded.

```
<script>
  var customMarker = {
    Groep: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
    },
    Hunt: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
    },
    Hint: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'
    }
  };

    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $mapslat; ?>, <?php echo $mapslng; ?>),
      zoom: <?php echo $mapszoom; ?>
    });
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: '<?php echo $kml; ?>',
      map: map
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl('modules/XMLmarkers.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var deelgebied = markerElem.getAttribute('deelgebied');
          var dag = markerElem.getAttribute('dag');
          var tijd = markerElem.getAttribute('tijd');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
              parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = type
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var content = dag + ' ' + tijd;
          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = content
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customMarker[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
        var path = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            path.push(point);
        }//finish loop

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        polyline.setMap(map);
      });
    }


  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Right now, the map draws lines between all markers, there is no filtering in the 'deelgebied' values. To achieve this, I wrote the following code to replace the loop:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].deelgebied === "Alpha") {
                var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                path.push(point);
            }
```

This code would replace the code just below var path []. Using this code, the map no longer draws any lines. *note: for testing purposes, I've just written the code to filter the Alpha markers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I first declared a var inside the loop for "deelgebied".
After that, I was able to simplify my if statement by just comparing the variable with a certain value.

```
var AlphaPath = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var markerdeelgebied = markers[i].getAttribute("deelgebied");
            if (markerdeelgebied == "Alpha") {
                var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                AlphaPath.push(point);
            }
        }
        var AlphaPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: AlphaPath,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        AlphaPolyline.setMap(map);
```